# KnockoutJs beta 3.0 - How do you destroy child elements?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, multidimensional-array

Currently i have a setup that looks like this:

```
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $(".removeButton").live("click", function() {
        viewModel.ProductCategories.destroy(ko.dataFor(this));
    });

    $(".renameButton").live("click", function() {
        ko.dataFor(this).Name("Renamed Successfully!");
    });
```

This is working fine for me until i introduce the concept of child elements. At that point the remove event no longer works for those items.

Is there a more generic way of "destroying" an element?

KO obviously knows the element i am clicking (as i am able to rename).

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Bikes","Parent":null,"Children":[{"Id":5,"Name":"Mountain Bikes","Parent":1,"Children":null},{"Id":6,"Name":"Road Bikes","Parent":1,"Children":null},{"Id":7,"Name":"Touring Bikes","Parent":1,"Children":null}]},{"Id":2,"Name":"Components","Parent":null,"Children":[{"Id":8,"Name":"Handlebars","Parent":2,"Children":null},{"Id":9,"Name":"Bottom Brackets","Parent":2,"Children":null},{"Id":10,"Name":"Brakes","Parent":2,"Children":null},{"Id":11,"Name":"Chains","Parent":2,"Children":null]}]
```

The events above will all work on any element (child or otherwise) except for remove which only works on root elements.

Can i call remove on an element itself or will I have to add some way of working out where it lives inside the array and destroying it like that?

for example; this is preferable:

```
    $(".removeButton").live("click", function() {
        ko.dataFor(this).destroy();
    });
```

to this:

```
    $(".removeButton").live("click", function() {
          viewModel.ProductCategories[someindex].Children.destroy(ko.dataFor(this));
    });
```

Thanks,
Kohan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is determining who the parent array is when trying to destroy an item.

Several options:
Rather than `ko.dataFor`, you can use `ko.contextFor` which will return an object that includes properties like `$data, $parent, $parents` and `$root`.

If your arrays have the same name, then you could do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xJjK8/

If your arrays have different names, then you could add a hint on the button element to understand the name of the parent like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/arpNx/

Otherwise, if you really wanted it to be generic, then you could use the `with` binding to force a scope block, which would allow you to access the parent array through `$parent`.  However, this will be the unwrapped array and we really would want the observableArray.  With some extra work, you could loop through the properties of the parent's parent and compare the underlying array with your unwrapped array to locate the actual observableArray that you would want to call destroy with your item.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bBVrE/

Finally, if you take care in the way that your objects are created you can push the destroy functionality to the item itself rather than needing access directly to the parent.  Here is a sample that shows adding a `destroyMe` method to an object that uses the parent that was passed to the constructor function: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Eeryh/

Comment: Awesome thanks for taking the time to explain this and supply some great code examples! - Just out of curiosity, each of my items have an Id and a parentId, can i use this to work out the parent at all (instead of using hints)? - http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/CMSz8/

Comment: I don't think that the parentId helps us too much in this case.  We can get to that object with $parent already, but need to know the name of the observableArray.